# Simplifying result

Tags: simplifying-expressions, formatting

I have an output of a operation:
 $\frac{\sqrt r}{\sqrt{r-2 s + \frac{s^2}{r}}}$.

I see, this can be simplified to  $\frac{1}{1-\frac{s}{r}}$ for r>0.

How do I make *Mathematica* impose this condition and make this simplification?

Comment: Both expressions are not equivalent. What if $r<0$?

Comment: Generally people appreciate if you provide your expressions as code that may be copied and pasted, e.g., as `Sqrt[r/(r - 2 s + s^2/r)]` and `1/(1 - s/r)`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. So, how to I impose a condition and get that result?

Comment: @PradipKattel look at `Assumptions`. It can be supplied as an option to `Simplify`.

Comment: with some assumptions `expr=Sqrt[r]/Sqrt[r-2 s+s^2/r]; Assuming[r>0&&r>s,Simplify[expr]]` gives `r/(r-s)`

Answer (score 3):

Both expressions are simply not equivalent (take $r<0$).

You can get the simplification that you probably implicitly made in your hand calculation, using `Assuming`:

```
Assuming[r > 0 && s < r, Simplify[Sqrt[r/(r - 2 s + s^2/r)]]]
(* r/(r - s) *)
```

As commented by b3m2a1, `Assumptions` can also be used as an option to `Simplify` as

```
Simplify[Sqrt[r/(r - 2 s + s^2/r)], Assumptions -> r > 0 && s < r]
```

providing the same result.

Comment: Thank you. :) :)

Comment: @PradipKattel You are welcome but please include Mathematica syntax as suggested by b3m2a1 to make a nice question. Just click on "edit".